Design a Data Structure for Efficient Key-Value Operations with Top K Check in c++
Data Structure Requirements
Design a data structure that supports the following operations:

Insertion: Insert a key-value pair.
Deletion: Delete a key-value pair.
Check Top K: Given an integer k and a key, check whether the value associated with the key is among the top K maximum values in the structure.

I was asked this question in an interview and I didn't know how to answer it definitively,
I know the solution is with 2 hashing tables, one hashing table with a key and a value, a second hashing table according to the key, this is the value and the value is the key,
They point to the same member, so when deleting and updating it will be logn
The goal is for the third function to be at o1
It is called say 1000000 times and the rest of the functions are in the 1000 area
That's why it needs to be faster.
std::map The second hash table will be
Because it is a sorted hash table like a red black tree, my problem was how do I access the n-k member
To know its size and compare if it is one of the big K, the problem is that it is impossible to know the index of an element in a hash table in o(1)

Side note: When I'm asking a question like this, I'm not looking for a solution. I'm looking for the candidate's problem-solving approach. If a candidate spits out an answer by rote, all I learn is they've got a good memory.

Side note to side note : On the other hand, if the problem describes a common problem used in the field I'm hiring for and the problem has a well-known solution that every viable candidate already knows, at that point I'm expecting a rote answer and using the question as a filter.

Given the requirement as stated, I don't think you need to be able to get from a value back to its key for the top-K inquiry.

Also, you mention "O(1)" but I don't see complexity requirements on any of the initial list, so I would not assume that anything is required to be O(1).

There's a data structure called a "heap" which is used for efficiently answering "what are the top K values in my dataset".  Not to be confused with dynamic memory allocation.

It's easy to make the third function O(1), as long as you don't mind the first two O(N).
To do it, you'd split your storage into a hash table containing keys and indices, and a vector of values with the key associated with each.
To do an insert, you do a sorted insertion into the vector. As you shift elements to make space for sorted insertion of the new element, you use the key stored with that value to access the hash table and increment the index for that element. When you've inserted the element in the vector, you insert the key and the index to the new item in the hash table.
Likewise, to do a deletion, you look the key up in the hash table, delete it from the hash table, and the value from the vector. As you shift the elements "above" that element in the vector to fill the gap, you use the key to go into the hash table and decrement the index stored with the key.
When you want to check for an element being in the top K, a lookup in the hash table gives you that item's rank directly.
If you wanted something more "balanced", giving O(log N) for all operations, you could create a hash table of keys and values, and an order statistic tree of values. Insertion and deletion would be just the normal insertion and deletion into/from the hash table and order statistic tree, and the top-K check would mean a lookup in the hash table to find the value, and search in the order statistic tree to find the rank.
In case you're unfamiliar with it, an order statistic tree is like a normal binary search tree, with one addition: along with the data you'd normally store, each node stores the number of descendants it has.
The rank of the root node is root->descendant_count - root->right->descendant_count (possibly +1) If root->right is a null pointer, that's obviously equivalent to a descendant count of 0.
Then as you descend right or left, you keep a running count, adding if you descend to the right, and subtracting if you descend to the left, to keep track of the rank of each node you descend to. With a balanced tree, you reach the node you care about in O(log N) steps, so the overall complexity is O(log N).
As you're maintaining your balanced tree, you need to rotate nodes around, and adjust counts as you do so, but (again) that's limited to O(log N) operations.

Insert and delete would be O(N) with fairly low probability.  Insert will need a heap regeneration only if (a) replacing an existing element and (b) the old value was in the top k and (c) the new value is less.  (b) is pretty rare.  With deletion, (a) and (c) are implied, and condition (b) will determine when it's slow.  Complexity is something like "O(k) + O(N) with probability k/N" which averages to O(k), although individual rare actions are O(N)

Degenerate cases such as "Performing many deletions, sequenced in descending order of value" would be expensive.

Your answer seems logical and I thought about it during the interview,
According to what was seen from the interviewer, there is a possibility that insertion and deletion will be log(n) and a check if the value is one of the larger K will be performed despite this in o(1)
